# Are these precautions sufficient for scam baiting?

Tags: privacy, anonymity

I'm a tired of these stupid scammers trying to rip off fellow university students desperate for housing, so as for some free time activity I thought I'd try and do some scam baiting, and send him to MoneyGram and Western Union a few times in vain for the fun of it :)

- I will use a **free online gmx account for the email**.
- I will create a **fake name and cover story**.

Questions:

- I have **never really used a service like tor, but is this necessary to ensure my protection**? Is this sort of information encoded in metadata? I could also use one of the university computers, would this help?
- Are there **any other precautions I should take**?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, scammers aren't technical people, and they won't look for your IP address in mail headers (since they sometimes leave theirs). Find a mail provider that doesn't forward it, just to be on the safe side.

This extremely entertaining resource, [419eater.com](http://www.419eater.com/html/baiting.htm), should give you the basics. As far as safety is concerned, it boils down to not giving out personal information.

I wouldn't go as far as using Tor for this, but it can't hurt anyway.

Comment: Just wondering- could there be a connection between a generic university computer logged on with my credentials and then a fake email sent to the scammer from that computer?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, unless your university recieves a complaint and decides to investigate who sent the email.